# DateList not using current year when a year is not specified

Tags: bugs, date-and-time, version-8, documentation

**Bug introduced in 8.0 and fixed in 9.0**

---

According to the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DateList.html) when using `DateList` but not giving it a year it should use the current year. It is not doing that for me. Instead it uses 1900. Evaluating the example in the documentation:

```
DateList[{"2/15", {"Month", "Day"}}]
```

results in

```
{1900, 2, 15, 0, 0, 0.}
```

when I would expect

```
{2012, 2, 15, 0, 0, 0.}
```

Am I reading the documentation wrong, or do I have some setting set wrong somewhere, or is this a bug if some kind?

Comment: I get the same 1900 result (Mma 8.0.4, Win7) and yes, the documentation does explicitly say that. Interestingly the documentation example of `DateList[{"2/15", {"Month", "Day"}}]` has an *integer* zero in the seconds position, instead of `0.`. Very odd! I think you might have found a bug.

Comment: I guess the problem is only with the `DateList[{string, {e1, e2, ...}]` input. Others use the current year. For example, `DateList["23 Nov"]` or even `DateList["23/11"]`, although the latter gives a warning that it is ambiguous

Comment: On version 7 under Windows 7 for entry `DateList[{"2/15", {"Month", "Day"}}]` I get output `{2012, 2, 15, 0, 0, 0}`.

Comment: I get {2012, 2, 15, 0, 0, 0} on "7.0 for Linux x86 (32-bit) (November 11, 2008)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in V8, it works in V7 and now in V9.